# How to avoid automatic return in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am new to TCL and I would like to run my script without returning any intermediate results to the screen ( unless asked to do so). How to stop automatic returns in TCL? Let me ask my question with a simple example

```
set a 10
```

This returns '10' back to the screen. I want to know how to stop this automatic return after command execution.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how ``set a 10`` is printing anything, unless you mean you're using a shell...

Comment: Must be interactive use. Tcl interactive shells print the contents of the result after each [complete](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/info.htm#M10) typed-in line. Non-interactive code doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
proc main {} {
    return
}
main
```

`tclsh test.tcl`: its really not going to print anything. However, neither will a script that just contains `set a 10`. You need to explore the difference between the interactive interpreter which runs a REPL style interface (read, eval, print, loop) and the non-interactive interpreter which evaluates your scripts.

In an interactive session you can add a junk command on the end of the line to suppress output. For instance, if you have to read a large string - to avoid having it printed out to the console you can use: `set data [read $filehandle]; string length $data`

Comment: Thank you very much for the information ! Yes, I was implementing my script using a shell.